# Boost Filesystem exists Access violation

Tags: c++, boost, mfc

I have a Problem with `boost::filesystem::exists(pathName)`.

When the folder did not exists the method returns `false` as expected.
If the Folder exists it throws an exception in the `make_permissions(const path& p, DWORD attr)` Method of the Boost File `operations.cpp`.

This is the code from that file

```
if (equal_string_ordinal_ic(ext.c_str(), L".exe")
  || equal_string_ordinal_ic(ext.c_str(), L".com")
  || equal_string_ordinal_ic(ext.c_str(), L".bat")
  || equal_string_ordinal_ic(ext.c_str(), L".cmd"))
  prms |= fs::owner_exe | fs::group_exe | fs::others_exe;
return prms;
```

The Message is:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in LineSync.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

This is thrown on the `if` Statement. 
I use this Method inside a MFC Application under Windows 10. On Windows 7 the Problem did not exist.

If I create a sample Windows Console Application on Windows 10, the Problem also did not happen.

This is the Code which did not work on the `MFC` Project but did work on an Windows 10 Console Application.

```
boost::filesystem::path pathDir(L"logs");
if (!boost::filesystem::exists(pathDir)) {
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(pathDir);
}
```

Changing to `boost::filesystem::is_directory(pathDir)` did also result in the exception on the MFC Project

Is there a Problem with MFC and Windows 10?
Or is there a better way to check if a specific directory exists?

EDIT 2:

This is an example which should cause the error on Windows with Boost 1.66

```
bool dummy = boost::filesystem::exists("logs");

class Demo {
public:
    ~Demo() {
        std::cout << boost::filesystem::path("logs").string() << std::endl;
    }
};

Demo d;

int main()
{
    Demo();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is not in Boost, it's in your code, the code you do not show us.  It could also be a problem in how you use the Boost library and how it was built. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The address shown in the message strongly suggests that a null pointer is somehow involved.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/12987).

Comment: Just because this kind of an exception gets thrown on a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug or the problem is. The problem can be anywhere else in your code, which is why a [mcve] that reproduces the problem is required before anyone can give you an answer.

Comment: What does the stack trace tell you? What happens if you step through the code with your debugger?

Comment: Does the problem only occur when you run it before main?

Comment: Yes it's a bug like G.M mentioned in his comment

Comment: Yes it's absolutely a boost bug since I've seen it too in 1.66. The function equal_string_ordinal_ic is NULL, so the call to is_directory fails with a null pointer exception. This is a global initialisation problem in boost - if your code uses boost from the global scope (e.g. you have a global class instance that does something in its constructor) then your code may be called before boost's globals. The workaround is to defer whatever you did in the ctor to somewhere else, or change the lifetime of the object so it is created after global is set up, e.g. some kind of Foo::getInstance() helper

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to check if a specific directory exists?

You can also use [PathFileExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584(v=vs.85).aspx) with MFC.

As the MSDN says:

> Determines whether a path to a file system object such as a file or folder is valid.

I have used this function many times with no issues. As indicated in the article you do have to link in the **shell lightweight API** for it to work.

Comment: The `PathFileExists()` reference mentions a `MAX_PATH` limitation though. The reference does not state whether this can be circumvented by using "\\?\" prefix or by opting in to remove the `MAX_PATH` limitation without using the "\\?\" prefix which is available since Windows 10, version 1607. The reference of [`GetFileAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx), which can also be used to check if a file exists, explicitly mentions these possibilities.

Comment: @zett42 Interesting. I don't know the answer to that one!